# How to Modify url in php.. i want to add some extra text at the end of output url

Tags: php, hyperlink, youtube

`$this->settings[''].'extractVideoID($groups[2]).'&type=Download" target="_blank"class="vidscrab"title="Download this video">Download`

Here is the code and the Result is `http://vidscrab.com/getvideo.php?videoid=yYUKp7SPj1Y`

i want to add some extra words after link eg `&type=Download`

i need this output `http://vidscrab.com/getvideo.php?videoid=yYUKp7SPj1Y&type=Download`

Please Help

Comment: can you add the whole anchor tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $(this).prop("href", $(this).prop("href") + "&type=Download");
});
```